# Flash for iPhone Embedding resource folder?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, loading

I am writing a flash game that I package as an iPhone app using FDT5.5.
I would like to be able to load images and sounds from a resource folder to avoid having to embed everything.
Is it possible to include a folder in the compile process that i can load from in my game?

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, but I don't believe that is possible to do with an iPhone app.